# idle speculation about gui recovery

Tags: x11, fsck

Firstly this is not a big issue as the machine that inspired this question is defective and will not be used in production as the serial ports are borked and the video card only works in graphics mode and neither condition is acceptable, but . . .

What if there was a computer that did not have either serial ports or a video card that supported text modes (and lets ignore macs as early ones had serial ports and recent ones work fine in text mode) and we wanted to run UNIX or Linux on such a box, Has anyone put out an early X11 based distro which runs fsck and whatnot after starting the X server?

(yes I know I am also ignoring the frame buffer which is the right solution, but . . . )

Comment: yeah if you have a framebuffer driver you can use the framebuffer console fbcon "In the x86 architecture, the framebuffer console is optional, and
some even treat it as a toy. For other architectures, it is the only available
display device, text or graphical."  My memory suggested it was added to work on Amiga, which I don't think had a text mode as such.  It's suggested that m68k was the first port of Linux http://www.linux-m68k.org/faq/history.html

Comment: @sourcejedi, I know that the frame buffer is the right solution (i even said so in the question), and I have used it (although not on this particular machine), but last time I checked the frame buffer didn't have any nice toolkits for building GUIs, and since this is defiantly a deep roving left field question I was kind of hoping for pretty (for any given value of pretty, I use ratpoison and like it) maybe with a animated progress bar.

Comment: plymouth and its predecessor RHGB use X11 if possible.  However, I'm pretty sure the details mode goes back to text mode.  I'm fuzzy on what exactly happens when fsck is required.

Comment: IIRC there's a number of Q&A's that describe how to make your own live USB stick for a number of distributions, so nothing prevents you from configuring one to start X with an xterm after boot. But I don't think anyone has done this, because this situation is quite specific, and a number of other solutions (serial USB dongle, framebuffer, just put in a different video card) come to mind first ...